# What is the vector product $(x\wedge y)\wedge z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, self-learning, lie-algebras

Here's an exercise from my [book](https://books.google.it/books?id=PQ8GCAAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=introduction%20to%20ring%20theory%20paul%20cohn&source=bl&ots=wpO9NMDUUL&sig=yBATdrbmgRJLnBoVE4PT6tTGANs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UUWcVZCcB8P_UtmpgYgN&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20ring%20theory%20paul%20cohn&f=false) (exercise 10, chapter 2.1)

> Show that the three-dimensional vector space $V=R^3$ forms an associative algebra with respect to the operation $x\uparrow y=(x_1y_1,x_2y_2,x_3y_3)$. Using the shift operator $S$ defined by $xS=(x_2,x_3,x_1)$, find an expression in terms of $\uparrow$ for the vector product $(x\wedge y)\wedge z$? and deduce that $V$ with the product $x\wedge y$ is a Lie Algebra

What does the author means by the vector product? What do those wedges mean in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: So V ^ W probably means the cross product between V and W. We use 'V x W' to note that operation on my country

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd never seen it denoted like this, or called 'vector product'

Comment: It's the French notation for the cross-product, which is called `vector product`, as in Italian.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra